# How to do matrix multiplication with `ModelMatrix` object in Julia?

Tags: matrix, dataframe, julia

I have no experience in the `DataFrame` in R, and I don't actually understand `ModelMatrix`.

I used it to transfer the `DataFrame` object to a "matrix" with one additional column consisting entirely 1 value. It is helpful for linear regression. However, I found Julia does not support matrix multiplication for `ModelMatrix`.

When I tried:

```
# feature is a DataFrames.ModelMatrix{Array{Float64,2}} object
println(feature' * feature)
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching *(::DataFrames.ModelMatrix{Array{Float64,2}}, ::DataFrames.ModelMatrix{Array{Float64,2}})
```

If one tries to convert `ModelMatrix` to `Array` using:

```
feature_array = convert(Array, feature)
```

Then there is an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type DataFrames.ModelMatrix{Array{Float64,2}} to an object of type Array{T,N}
```

Therefore I am wondering how to convert `ModelMatrix` to another object which Julia can do matrix multiplication (*) with, like `Array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [source of `ModelMatrix`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/src/statsmodels/formula.jl#L55-L58) you can see the object has a property `m` which is the value of the underlying matrix. You can pull it out using `mm.m` (where `mm` is a `ModelMatrix`).

### Example:

#### Generating a `ModelMatrix`:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(X = randn(4), Y = randn(4), Z = randn(4))
4×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ X        │ Y          │ Z        │
├─────┼──────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.766271 │ 0.669007   │ 0.232803 │
│ 2   │ 2.08208  │ 0.239115   │ 0.855068 │
│ 3   │ -1.48009 │ 0.00220079 │ 0.105638 │
│ 4   │ -1.57438 │ 0.650456   │ 0.557467 │

julia> mf = ModelFrame(Z ~ X + Y, df)
DataFrames.ModelFrame(4×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Z        │ X        │ Y          │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.232803 │ 0.766271 │ 0.669007   │
│ 2   │ 0.855068 │ 2.08208  │ 0.239115   │
│ 3   │ 0.105638 │ -1.48009 │ 0.00220079 │
│ 4   │ 0.557467 │ -1.57438 │ 0.650456   │
...

julia> mm = ModelMatrix(mf)
DataFrames.ModelMatrix{Array{Float64,2}}(4x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0   0.766271  0.669007  
 1.0   2.08208   0.239115  
 1.0  -1.48009   0.00220079
 1.0  -1.57438   0.650456  ,[0,1,2])
```

#### Using the `ModelMatrix`:

```
julia> m = mm.m
4x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0   0.766271  0.669007  
 1.0   2.08208   0.239115  
 1.0  -1.48009   0.00220079
 1.0  -1.57438   0.650456  

julia> m * rand(3,1)
4x1 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.9474  
  3.08515 
 -0.522879
 -0.371708
```